# Ambari server setup: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm trying to setup Hadoop on my EC2 instance using [this tutorial](http://hortonworks.com/blog/deploying-hadoop-cluster-amazon-ec2-hortonworks/). I'm trying to setup the ambari server when I get this error:

```
[root@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ec2-user]# ambari-server setup
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.6
Setup ambari-server
Checking SELinux...
WARNING: Could not run /usr/sbin/sestatus: OK
Ambari-server daemon is configured to run under user 'root'. Change this setting [y/n] (n)?
Adjusting ambari-server permissions and ownership...
Checking iptables...
Checking JDK...
JCE Policy archive already exists, using /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/jce_policy-6.zip
Completing setup...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/ambari-server.py", line 4236, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/sbin/ambari-server.py", line 4055, in main
    setup(options)
  File "/usr/sbin/ambari-server.py", line 2089, in setup
    retcode = configure_os_settings()
  File "/usr/sbin/ambari-server.py", line 1909, in configure_os_settings
    os_name = os_info[0].lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I'm really unsure how this is happening and don't know what to do fix this. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** I looked at the code at found this:

```
  os_info = platform.linux_distribution(
    None, None, None, ['SuSE', 'redhat' ], 0
  )
  os_name = os_info[0].lower()
```

It appears that `platform.linux_distribution` is creating an array with it's parameters and doing something else to it. I can't find the implementation of the function in the file and there are several files that are in its same directory, still not sure what should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, I removed the 3 `None` objects and removed the 2-size array and made them their own parameters. [However now Ambari is causing another problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742079/ambari-server-setup-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)